# Using XPath to retrieve information from a XML File based upon a XML Schema created by me

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm developing a markup language and I started with defining a DTD.
As I was finishing my DTD, I noticed I needed a stronger type of document for my language so I went for an XML Schema based upon my DTD. Now my question is: can I use XPath on a XML document based on my XML Schema?

Example:
My document starts with:

```
<notation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ... xsi:noNameSpaceLocatio="locationOfMyFile">
```

Now, using XPath will I be able to retrieve all the informations that I want or do I need to do something else? Because I red online that with XML Schemas, XPath's Operations are very limited.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, regardless of whether you've written a DTD, XSD, another schema, or no schema for your XML, you'll be able to use XPath to select parts of your XML all the same.

- Think of an **XML schema** as a mechanism for ***defining the vocabulary and
  grammar*** of XML.
- Think of **XPath** as a mechanism for ***selecting parts*** of XML.

They're orthogonal.<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup>Some XML schema, including XSD and Schematron, use XPath for selecting XML parts in the course of defining allowed names and structure, but that doesn't change how XPath can separately be used to select parts from an XML document apart from any XML schema.)</sub>